# phonegap cli blackberry 10

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, cordova-cli

I'm having some trouble building a blackberry 10 version of my app using Phonegap's CLI (Phonegap 3.4.1).

Logically the command should be:

```
 phonegap build blackberry10
```

but this returns the following errors :

```
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/build.js:73
    self.phonegap.emit('log', 'detecting', platform.human, 'SDK environment...
                                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'human' of undefined
at BuildCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/build.js:73:52)
at BuildCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/build.js:55:10)
at PhoneGap.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/util/command.js:28:25)
at CLI.module.exports [as build] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/cli/build.js:35:14)
at CLI.module.exports [as argv] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/cli/argv.js:66:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js:26:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Everything works fine for android and iOS, I have the blackberry 10 sdk installed and the directory is in my PATH variable. It seems that blackberry10 isn't recognized, perhaps my command is wrong? (i've tried blackberry-10, qnx ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Phonegap build service doesn't support BlackBerry10.

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/introduction_supported_platforms.md.html#Supported%20Platforms

If you have added the platform already

```
cordova platform add blackberry10
```

your best bet would be to use the cordova syntax to access the engine directly

```
cordova build blackberry10
```

This will definitely give you the expected results (as long as you have the signing keys configured :))

Comment: In the docs for the phonegap cli, they say that we can locally build blackberry 10 projects, do I have to install cordova too then, but I thought that for local builds these were the same things?[link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Comment: You could use the command `phonegap local build blackberry10` otherwise the cordova command can be installed through [http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/the-nodejs-command-line-interface-for-phonegap.html](npm install cordova)

Comment: strangely enough phonegap local build blackberry10 wasn't recognized correctly, I resolved the issue by installing cordova